# Are there any real-world applications for the logistic map (as defined in chaos theory)?

Tags: dynamical-systems, harmonic-analysis, nonlinear-system, chaos-theory, algorithmic-randomness

Is the logistic map only useful for theoretically exploring nonlinear dynamical systems, or can it be applied to real-world scenarios in any practical way?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovJcsL7vyrk) answers your question and you must have seen this before. If you have read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) for this closely

---

> This nonlinear difference equation is intended to capture two effects:

1. reproduction where the population will increase at a rate proportional to the current population when the population size is small.
2. starvation (density-dependent mortality) where the growth rate will decrease at a rate proportional to the value obtained by taking the theoretical "carrying capacity" of the environment less the current population.

---

This quality of unpredictability and apparent randomness led the logistic map equation to be used as a pseudo-random number generator in early computers.

---

This [article](https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/12/5/829/pdf) is very helpful.

If you only want the practical applications then skip ahead to the Butterfly Effect in [this](https://geoffboeing.com/2015/03/chaos-theory-logistic-map/) article.

PS. The notes after each horizontal rule are not continuations of each other but rather excerpts from mentioned articles.